# How to make in-line footnote and citation clickable?

Tags: cross-referencing

Here's what I want to do. I've seen this in many papers but not sure how to accomplish it.

1. In-line footnote, number shows up either in crimson red color or inside a rectangle. It is clickable, i.e. when you click on it you go to the footnote.
2. In-line reference, for example (John Doe, 1999). It is clickable, i.e. when you click it you go to the References section of the paper.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 1):

To just create a simple hyperlink, this worked for me: `\usepackage{hyperref}` at the top after the other use packages, and `\href{url}{linktext}` where I want to put a link.
and please search `hyperref` on StackOverflow, this question already has some good answers.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question right, then you have to use an additional package...

I would propose the "hyperref" package!

[Description and source for the hyperref package](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/)